# Can Format Win 10 mess up my boot menu?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows

I'm new, recently I was trying ubuntu, (I used it before like 9 years ago) this is the second time I install it and use it, (I wasn't sure about to install it). But now I like it, even more than windows, that I use it as my primary O.S.

Since my Windows 10 is working very slow. To be more specific now I'm using the Boot Menu of ubuntu to chosee between Ubuntu or Windows 10. I want to format Windows 10, but I wonder if doing this will mess up the boot menu of Ubuntu. Since I don't want to have to fix this thing in case something happen.

Is this possible? Or formatting windows 10 will not change the stock Ubuntu Boot Menu?

Comment: So you're using GRUB? And you want to reset windows 10 if I understand correctly?

Comment: It is always a good idea to **backup** your current system before doing things with the partition table or partitions, because things could go wrong. Normally it would not affect the Ubuntu system (including the bootloader grub and its grub menu), if you format a partition, that is not directly involved in booting or running Ubuntu. So it should work well to format the Windows partition and reuse it for other purposes, for example as a data partition. You can use `gparted` for this purpose.

Comment: yeah guys it mess up grub... first I tried to see if I can recover it from windows, but fail... so i had to flash ubuntu in an usb stick, and run live-cd to recover grub from terminal. thank you.